# Race condition in Stateful widget with parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I'm having a race condition of data from a BehaviorSubject's stream not populating/updating the state before the build function returns.

content-detail.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:domain_flutter/application-bloc.dart';
import 'package:domain_flutter/content.dart';
import 'package:domain_flutter/tag_chips.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class ContentDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final String slug;

  ContentDetail({Key key, this.slug}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ContentDetailState();
}

class _ContentDetailState extends State<ContentDetail> {
  Content _content = Content();

  _getContent() {
    print(widget.slug);
      applicationBloc.contentOutput.map( (contents) =>
      contents.where((item) => item.slug == widget.slug).toList())
          .listen((data) => {
                if (this.mounted) {
                  setState(() => _content = data.first)
                }
              });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getContent();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: _content != null ? Text(_content.title) : Text(''),
      ),
      body:
      SafeArea(
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                title: Text(_content.title,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                subtitle: Text(
                  DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(_content.changed),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                ),
              )),
              TagChips(_content.tags),
              CachedNetworkImage(
                  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  imageUrl: 'https://domain.tld/files/${_content.image}'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The widget renders, but before it's rendered I receive an error.
If content isn't initialized I receive a different error.

What I mean by content initialized is

```
Content _content = Content();
```

content initialized:

```
The following assertion was thrown building ContentDetail(dirty, state: _ContentDetailState#15727):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 269 pos 10: 'data != null'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///home/darko/AndroidStudioProjects/domain_flutter/lib/main.dart:24:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:269:10)
#3      _ContentDetailState.build (package:domain_flutter/content_detail.dart:41:35)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4047:27)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3941:15)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
...
```

content uninitialized:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building ContentDetail(dirty, state: _ContentDetailState#2be0b):
The getter 'title' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: title

User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///home/darko/AndroidStudioProjects/domain_flutter/lib/main.dart:24:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _ContentDetailState.build (package:domain_flutter/content_detail.dart:53:38)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4047:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3941:15)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
...
```

So yeah, there is no data when it's trying to render the component... or Widget/s rather.

I should probably show my `applicationBloc`

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:domain_flutter/application-entities.dart';
import 'package:domain_flutter/content.dart';
import 'package:domain_flutter/tag.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class ApplicationBloc {
  final _applicationEntities = ApplicationEntities();

  Sink<List<Content>> get contentInput => _contentInputController.sink;
  Sink<List<Tag>> get tagInput => _tagInputController.sink;

  Stream<List<Content>> get contentOutput => _contentOutputSubject.stream;
  Stream<List<Tag>> get tagOutput => _tagOutputSubject.stream;

  final _contentInputController = StreamController<List<Content>>();
  final _tagInputController = StreamController<List<Tag>>();

  final _contentOutputSubject = BehaviorSubject<List<Content>>();
  final _tagOutputSubject = BehaviorSubject<List<Tag>>();

  ApplicationBloc() {
    _contentInputController.stream.listen(_handleContentInput);
    _tagInputController.stream.listen(_handleTagInput);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _contentInputController.close();
    _contentOutputSubject.close();
    _tagInputController.close();
    _tagOutputSubject.close();
  }

  void _handleContentInput(List<Content> contentList) {
    _applicationEntities.updateContent(contentList);
    _contentOutputSubject.add(contentList);
  }
  void _handleTagInput(List<Tag> tagList) {
    _applicationEntities.updateTags(tagList);
    _tagOutputSubject.add(tagList);
  }
}

final applicationBloc = ApplicationBloc();
```

You probably guessed, the idea is to load the JSON from a web service then provide it application wide via global variable.
That works without errors for everything but the `ContentDetail` class.

This `ContentDetail` class is almost a copy of another component that does almost the same, it filters by a tag slug and renders a list of `Content`.
This here only wants 1 item from the stream, `Content` with a specific `slug` property.

```
class Content {
// ...
  final String slug;
}
```

As you can see I'm passing the `slug` in the `ContentDetail` constructor and my `_ContentDetailState` is accessing its property via `widget.slug`.

The `_getContent()` function of the `ContentListByTagSlug` class in comparison:

```
  void _getContent() {
    applicationBloc.contentOutput.map(
            (contents) => contents.where(
                    (item) => item.tags.any((tag) => tag.slug == widget.tag.slug)
            ).toList()
    )
        .listen((data) => {
              if (this.mounted) {
                  setState(() => {content = data})
                }
            });
  }
```

This works, while only getting 1 item from it doesn't (see 1st code snippet).

This is how I define the `FlatButton` to open the `ContentDetail` page:

```
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Read more'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          ContentDetail(slug: content[index].slug))),
            ),
```

It's valid, the slug is passed as the result of the print function indicates.

I'm not sure what to do to ascertain that the `_content` variable is populated before the build function is executed.
In Angular one creates a resolver, which then populates data before the component is created/initialized.

In Flutter?

Note I'm not using the bloc package, but put the streams in a dedicated class, then use setState to update the state in the listening classes, as the bloc package seems overkill for this scenario.
3 widgets (4 if you count the drawer)
1 displaying an unfiltered list
2 displaying a list filtered by tag slug
3 displaying one item filtered by tag slug
only the latter has errors.

update1: I even removed the `if (this.mounted)` check in `_getContent()` and I'm calling `_getContent()` again in the builder if `_content` is null.
Then I have changed `_content` to be a List and am getting `_content.first.title` which results in

```
Bad state: No element
```

But the widget is still rendered correctly.
So it seems that there are 2 invocations of the widget. One that throws errors, which is discarded and one that doesn't which is kept. I'm not familiar with the internals so that's my best guess.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49931743).

What I'm taking away from it is

- don't initialize variables that are meant to be filled by a stream
- provide a check in the builder whether the value to be filled in `null`
- if null render a loading screen else render the desired widget with populated state