# How to wait for async in initState

Tags: flutter

I have an async function that needs to be called in initState in an Stateful widget, but I cannot use await as initState is not async.

`sendHealthData` is `async` as it get some information from the Health Api, and then I need to send that information to HomeSubScreen which is another `StatefulWidget`. But at the time the HomeSubScreen is created, the `sendHealthData` method didn't get all the information, so If I try to send some value in a param to the `HomeSubScreen`, the value will be null.

How can I do that?

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sendHealthData();
    _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      HomeSubScreen(healthData),
    ];

  }
```

Update:
If I added a then() I get the following error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'elementAt' was called on null.
```

Code Updated:

```
@override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        sendHealthData().then((response){
             _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
                 HomeSubScreen(healthData),
              ];
        });


      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter, render widget after async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930180/flutter-render-widget-after-async-call)

Comment: use `Future.then()` then

Answer (score 12):

I'm giving you general idea of it.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  function().then((int value) {
    // future is completed you can perform your task 
  });

  function2(); // or you can simply call the method if you don't want anything to do after future completes
}

Future<int> function() async {
  // do something here 
}

Future<int> function2() async {
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: I think `setState(() {);` should be there inside `function().then((int value) {
    // future is completed you can perform your task 
  });` in order to change state after the result in fetched.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you can put `setState` in it if you want to reflect changes in UI. I just wanted to give an idea how it can be handled.

Comment: But the value I Need to update is in other StatefulWidget. Is the setState useful for this?

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: getYourDataFromApi(), 
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return Text('start widget');
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Awaiting result from api...');
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  },
)
```

Comment: This is the idiomatic answer. Effectively, you're wrapping the widget that needs to wait (could be a `MaterialApp` or any other widget) in a class that will wait until your `async` work is done, then returning whatever widget you like, optionally use the `Future`'s return  value in `case ConnectionState.done:`. The function call that you specify in the `future:` property can by any `async` function that does whatever work that you need to do (could be a bunch of stuff using `await`, etc). Whatever that function returns is available to you via `snapshot.data`.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot await for async function in the initState, but a little trick is to use the Then keyword to execute code after that future complete.

eg:

```
@override


void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sendHealthData().then((response){

      _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
        HomeSubScreen(response),
      ];

    });


  }
```

and the function must be like:

```
Future sendHealthData() async{}
```

Comment: When I apply this solution I get an error saying:
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'elementAt' was called on null. This only happends when I put the _widgetOptions inside the then function

Comment: I am sorry but without the full code, it is difficult to address the error! can you post it?