# Fetch await future data in initState Flutter gives null value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

Trying to fetch data in initState using async/await gives null value every-time. How can I set value once await complete

```
void initState() {
   convertFutureMakes().then((result) {
     setState(() {
       _makesList = result;
     });
   });
   CarMake brand = _makesList.firstWhere((obj)=>obj.name == make);
   super.initState();
}
```

_makesList is always null due to which it gives an error when I use that list. Here is the convertFutureMakes method

```
convertFutureMakes() async{
  List<CarMake> makes = await getCarMakes();
  return makes;
}
```

getCarMakes fetch data from an Api. But it takes some time and it not wait for that. How can I make sure it have data before usage or fix that issue in other way

Comment: What's the makes return value in convertfututmremakes function?

Comment: @proversion list of objects(CarMake)

Comment: If you are receiving a Json Object you could use a Future builder and pass Snapshot conditions such as hasData/error etc. To selectively build widget or anything for that matter. If you need help with that please share the Json File example/template

Answer (score 1):

The line below:

```
CarMake brand = _makesList.firstWhere((obj)=>obj.name == make);
```

needs to be in the then() callback, otherwise it is nondeterministic whether it will execute before or after:

```
_makesList = result;
```

Put another way, the code after convertFutureMakes().then() is running *before* the then() callback is called and that's why there's no value.  Realistically, there never will be a value.

Try:

```
 convertFutureMakes().then((result) {
     setState(() {
       _makesList = result;
       CarMake brand = _makesList.firstWhere((obj)=>obj.name == make);
     });
   });
```

Comment: But i have to use that results inside widget also and do some ...there it gives null when I fetch inside data of them

Comment: Check out FutureBuilder.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930180/flutter-render-widget-after-async-call and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYN46233cws.