# Best practice on how to display a widget which content is depending on an async call?

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically topic.
I am trying to display an image slider with content that I pull from a db. I'm calling for this data in the initstate method. I have managed to do a couple of workarounds, but none of them seem clean enough. I don't necessarily need to call it from initstate, but I need that it shows up as I open the screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter, render widget after async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930180/flutter-render-widget-after-async-call)

Answer (score 0):

If it's an image, you can use a package called blurhash, Google it for more information regarding that.