# SecureStorage reads null in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

This is a separate class for SecureStorage which I have created.

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class SecureStorage {
  final _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

  Future writeSecureData(String key, String value) async {
    var writeData = await _storage.write(key: key, value: value);
    return writeData;
  }

  Future readSecureData(String key) async {
    var readData = await _storage.read(key: key);
    return readData;
  }

  Future deleteSecureData(String key) async {
    var deleteData = await _storage.delete(key: key);
    return deleteData;
  }
}
```

So, From the sign in page, I write the data into the secure storage as shown in the screenshot below. When I print username and password at this stage, they are as expected.

[image]

But, while reading the data from the secure storage on splash screen, it always shows null. The code for the splash screen below:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final SecureStorage secureStorage = SecureStorage();

  //Fetching data from secureStorage
  SplashScreen() {
    secureStorage.readSecureData("email").then((value) => finalEmail = value);
    secureStorage.readSecureData("name").then((value) => finalName = value);
    print(finalEmail);
    print(finalName);
  } ...remaining code
```

Everytime I hot reload the application, the data is lost. I don't even know if the data is written in the first place. How do I tackle this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
SplashScreen() {
    secureStorage.readSecureData("email").then((value) => finalEmail = value);
    secureStorage.readSecureData("name").then((value) => finalName = value);
    print(finalEmail);
    print(finalName);
  }
```

Since the program was asynchronous, the widget rendered before the values were changed. I wrapped the main widget in future builder and it worked great.

This worked as a reference: [Flutter, render widget after async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930180/flutter-render-widget-after-async-call/49931743)